# Efficient way to track inter-runtime changes to a directory?

Tags: python, filesystems, cross-platform, filesystemwatcher

I know that I can use a library such as Watchdog in order to track changes to a directory during the runtime of a Python program. However, what if I want to track changes to the same directory *between* invocations of the same program? For example, if I have the following dir when I run the program the first time:

*example/
    file1
    file2*

I then quit, delete one file, and add another one:

*example/
    file2
    file3*

Now, when I start the program the second time, I would like to efficiently get a summary of the changes done ("deleted file1, added file3") to the directory since I last ran the program.

*I know* that I could brute force a solution by (for example) saving a list of all files when the program quits, create a new list when it starts, and then compare the two. However, is there a more efficient way to do this - preferably one that makes use of the underlying OS/filesystem AND is deployable cross-platform?

Comment: One naive way is to write a script that will invoke watchdog, and then call your real script multiple times

Comment: Whats wrong with the brute force?

Comment: @SH- it is ugly, and I just feel there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: You could try to look at change dates of files and folders, but that might not be reliable for adds/deletes.  Really, your brute force solution seems the best.

Comment: Watchdog actually seems like overkill for your use case. It's packaged nicely, but you should be able to whip something up fairly quickly. You don't need real time notifications.

Comment: For Windows there is the [USN Journal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USN_Journal) for NTFS but not all filesystems on all OS' record file changes and if they don't do it then there's no other way than a brute force method